# Javascript can't find element by id?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test javascript</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var e = document.getElementById("db_info");
        e.innerHTML='Found you';
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="tables">

        </div>        
        <div id="db_info">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I use `alert(e);` it turns up `null`.... and obviously I don't get any "found you" on screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Food for thought: When does the JavaScript code block run? When is the DIV with the id "db_info" created and/or guaranteed to exist?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the element before it exists. You need to wait for the page to be fully loaded. A possible approach is to use the `onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var e = document.getElementById("db_info");
    e.innerHTML='Found you';
};
```

Most common JavaScript libraries provide a DOM-ready event, though. This is better, since `window.onload` waits for all images, too. You do not need that in most cases.

Another approach is to place the script tag right before your closing `</body>`-tag, since everything in front of it is loaded at the time of execution, then.

Comment: +1 for window.onload and for anonymous function ^^

Answer (score 3):

How will the browser know when to run the code inside script tag? So, to make the code run after the window is loaded completely,

```
window.onload = doStuff;

function doStuff() {
    var e = document.getElementById("db_info");
    e.innerHTML='Found you';
}
```

The other alternative is to keep your `<script...</script>` just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Script is called before element exists.

You should try one of the following:

1. wrap code into a function and use a body onload event to call it.
2. put script at the end of document
3. use defer attribute into script tag declaration

Answer (score 1):

The script is performed before the DOM of the body is built. Put it all into a function and call it from the `onload` of the body-element.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code either in onload event, either just before you close `body` tag.
You try to find an element wich is not there at the moment you do it.