# Can't run scripts on gmail in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome plugin but it is running on all google sites except gmail, how do I make it run on gmail?

My manifest file:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "drc",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["content.js", "onclic.js", "Jquery.js"],
      "css": ["drpdwn.css"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Append Test Text"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "https://mail.google.com/*",
    "http://mail.google.com/* "
  ]
}
```

Error I get is, cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Comment: There's probably something wrong in your manifest.json or relevant code. Add it to your question.

Comment: I only needed to let the page load first[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498482/javascript-cant-find-element-by-id?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Well, gmail is a dynamic AJAX-driven page so you need to use MutationObserver or check the presence of the element periodically in setInterval callback.