# function.php code related to Revolution Slider

Tags: javascript, wordpress, revolution-slider

i have set a simple JS, just an alert message on click of button with id "button". It is working fine when i insert the code inside Revolution Slider Custom CSS/JS field.

```html
function hello(){
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
jQuery("#button").click(hello);
```

But not working on the function.php file of the child theme, why is that?

```html
function button_fn() {
    ?>
        <script>
            function hello(){
                alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
            }
            jQuery("#button").click(hello);
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'button_fn');
```

Comment: Probably because this outputs the script element to early, before the element you are trying to access via ID even exists. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498482/javascript-cant-find-element-by-id

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery( document ).ready(function()`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
function button_fn() {
    <script>
    function hello(){
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    }
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(document).on('click', '#button', function(){ 
            hello();
        })
    })
    </script>
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'button_fn');
```

Comment: @HowardE thanx for remind. Answer has been updated now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to enqueue the script without any dependencies, so it's likely that jQuery hasn't been enqueued yet.  Instead of using `wp_enquque_scripts` try `wp_footer` with a priority higher than 20. 20 is where the enqueue scripts hook fires.

```
function button_fn() {
    ?>
        <script>
            function hello(){
                alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
            }
            jQuery("#button").on('click', function(){
                 hello()}
            );
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'button_fn', 30);
```