# How can I scroll down to the specific div when page loading?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an application with mega navigation which have list of items. Within another component I have same list with accordions. When I click on a item in mega nav it is redirecting to the component and accordion is going to expand of selected item.it is working fine. Now I want to scroll down to the expanded div when page is loading.

This is my code looks like

```
<div class="container">
<hr>
<div *ngFor="let category of parentData| async; let i = index" class="category-content">
  <div class="expanded-div" *ngIf="collapsible == category.id">
    
     {expanded accordion data goes here }}
  
  </div>


  <div *ngIf="collapsible != category.id">

     {{non-expanded accordion data goes here}}

  </div>
</div>
```

I tried anchor tag method also. But it is not working.
[I tried this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-an-html-page-to-a-given-anchor)

I tried this also in my .ts file inside the ngOninit()

```
document.getElementById("expanded-div").scrollIntoView();
```

it gives me below error.

> Object is possibly 'null'. ts(2531)

can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not** use setTimeout 1000.

As you're using async pipe, you can create an observable with pipe(tap) to know when the data is readed

```
parentDataExtend=this.parentData.pipe(tap(_=>{

  //this setTimeout without "pause", make that
  //document.getElementById("expanded-div").scrollIntoView();
  //is executed after paint the elements

  setTimeout(() =>{
     document.getElementById("expanded-div").scrollIntoView();
  })
})
```

And use

```
<div *ngFor="let category of parentDataExtend| async;..>
```

In this way, you don't depend how time spend the data to be loaded.

NOTE: If you're using an Input to pass the "parentData", you should define the parentDataExtend in a setter of the input

```
@Input('parentData') set _parentData(value:any[]){
   this.parentDataExtend=value.pipe(tap(_=>{...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided id to corresponding  block in html code.
You can do it like this:

```
<div class="expanded-div" id="expanded-div" *ngIf="collapsible == category.id">
    
     {expanded accordion data goes here }}
  
  </div>
```

or

in your `.ts` file use `document.getElementsByClassName()` instead of `document.getElementById()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried both ways. But nothing works

Answer (score 0):

It says "object is possibly null" because when you call any element selector like `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName` it's possible that no elements will match the selector and it will return `null`. Run this example to see what I mean

```js
console.log(
  document.getElementById('example')
);

console.log(
  document.getElementById('not-on-the-page')
);
```

```html
<span id="example">Hello</span>
```

Typescript it catching this possible error for you, so you need to deal with the fact that your selector might be null.  There are two ways you can do this:

1.) This is the best way. you save the element as a variable, and then check to see if that variable has a value or not.

```ts
const myEl = document.getElementById("expanded-div");
if(myEl){
  myEl.scrollIntoView();
} else {
  console.error('The element could not be found!')
}
```

2.) This will work, but I do not recommend it. By adding a `!` it's called a "non-null assertion" and this means you are telling TypeScript "I know better than you, and this element will exists 100% of the time no matter what. I do not recommend this way because if you are wrong, then your application will have a runtime error. This is much more fragile than the above method.

```ts
document.getElementById("expanded-div")!.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I tried this also. But it is not working. How ever this answer helps me to identify my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of attempts I realize that this happens because I tried to access the element before it is loading. I solved my issue by adding setTimeout()

```
setTimeout(() =>{
  document.getElementById("expanded-div").scrollIntoView();
},1000)
```

Comment: **not** use setTimeout 1000, see may answer.

Comment: It should be complete but who knows if the element will load within a second.
This question has a good suggestion in the answer using `window.onload`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498482/javascript-cant-find-element-by-id